# get max value after grouping two columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, max

I want to get the trip_time with the highest count for each age_group

| age_group | trip_time | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 - 30yrs | 01am | 23 |
| 18 - 30yrs | 02am | 2 |
| 18 - 30yrs | 03am | 213 |
| 31 - 50yrs | 01am | 74 |
| 31 - 50yrs | 02am | 211 |
| 31 - 50yrs | 03am | 852 |
| 51 - 70yrs | 01am | 23 |
| 51 - 70yrs | 02am | 11 |
| 51 - 70yrs | 03am | 101 |

Expected output:

| age_group | trip_time | counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18 - 30yrs | 03am | 213 |
| 31 - 50yrs | 03am | 852 |
| 51 - 70yrs | 03am | 101 |

```
trip_time_age_group.groupby(['age_group', 'trip_time'])['counts'].max()
```

But it gives me wrong result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupby 'age-group' and then use transform to get the max count for each age-group, which you then compare with the count of the DF, to get the resultset

```
df.loc[df.groupby('age_group')['counts'].transform('max').eq(df['counts'])]
```

```
    age_group trip_time  counts
2  18 - 30yrs      03am     213
5  31 - 50yrs      03am     852
8  51 - 70yrs      03am     101
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby only `age_group`, then find the rows in each group with the max `counts`.

```
df.groupby('age_group').apply(
    lambda sf: sf.loc[sf['counts'] == sf['counts'].max()]
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    age_group trip_time  counts
0  18 - 30yrs      03am     213
1  31 - 50yrs      03am     852
2  51 - 70yrs      03am     101
```

You could also do `sf.query('counts == counts.max()')` instead of `sf.loc[...]`.